# DialogFragment not showing custom layout

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I have a DialogFragment with a custom layout. Everything shows properly when the fragment is embedded in my activity using a FragmentTransaction, like so:

```
        getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .add(
            R.id.fragment_container,
            exampleDialogFragment,
            ExampleDialogFragment.TAG)
        .commit();
```

but when I do:

```
        exampleDialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), exampleDialogFragment.TAG);
```

the dialog only shows the 'Cancel' button. The stuff in the custom layout doesn't appear.

This is what my ExampleDialogFragment class looks like:

```
public class ExampleDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
     @NonNull LayoutInflater layoutInflater,
     @Nullable ViewGroup viewGroup,
     @Nullable Bundle bundle) {
          // Inflate layout and init views
  }
```

This documentation https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs#FullscreenDialog seems to imply that we don't need to override `onCreateDialog`, so I'm not doing that. However, it still doesn't look right. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking at this, my dialog had an outer ConstraintLayout. Changing it to a RelativeLayout fixed the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The comment worked for me. Thanks!